# How to update a field in MongoDB with new value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to go through records in a collection, where there is no longitude/latitude information in the coordinate field. Using Google's `geocode()` method I'm selecting records that have a location information to convert to coordinates and then to update the new value in the `coordinates` field, which would have been previously `null`.

Using the `find()` method, I'm getting the relevant records but this block of code does not seem to be executing, i.e. the records have not been updated with the coordinate information. This is the code:

```
cursor = coll.find(
                {"$and": [
                            {"coordinates":  {"$type":10}}, 
                            {"place": {"$ne": None}}
                    ]}, 
            {"coordinates": 1, "place": 1, "time_normal": 1, "_id": 1}, tailable = True, timeout = False)

while cursor.alive:
    counter=0
    g = geocoders.Google()
    try:
        doc = cursor.next()
        current_id = doc['_id']
        counter+=1
        print doc  
        placeName = doc['place']['full_name']
        loc = g.geocode(placeName)
        coll.update({"_id" : current_id},{"$set": {"coordinates": loc[1]}})
        print doc          
        time.sleep(0.15)                            
    except (ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError):
        pass

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

I cannnot see why the field is not being updated. I'm noticing that `print counter` returns 0.

Thanks

Comment: Is `coll` a capped collection?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, yes `coll` is capped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

You can simplify your `find` query a bit to remove the `$and` as including multiple fields in a query selector naturally 'ands' them:

```
cursor = coll.find(
    {
        {"coordinates":  {"$type":10}},
        {"place": {"$ne": None}}
    }, 
    {"coordinates": 1, "place": 1, "time_normal": 1, "_id": 1}, 
    tailable = True, timeout = False)
```

But that shouldn't be causing any problems and your `update` call looks good.  However, don't expect `doc` to be modified by the `update` call because it's a snapshot of what the document looked like at the time of the `find` call.  You'd need to call `find_one({"_id": current_id})` at that point to see the results of the update.

If it still looks like it isn't updating, see what the contents of `loc[1]` are before the update to make sure it's what you expect.

**UPDATE**

The problem is likely that you're trying to update a capped collection that's causing the size of the document to grow.  According to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/#recommendations-and-restrictions), that will cause the update to fail.

Comment: Thanks for the query tip, makes it easier. When I do `print loc[1]` it gives the coordinate information. When I run the code again it just repeats the whole collection again. I understand that `doc` is a snapshot, but I don't know how else to update the field.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Does 'grow' refer to the actual size of the document? If so would it be possible to set the value in another field to `null` to accommodate for an updated value?

Comment: @user94628 I don't know any more specifics beyond what's in the docs, but I would assume 'grow' to mean that it takes up even one more byte of space in the size of the doc (as they can't be moved around).  If you're very careful you might be able manipulate other fields to keep the overall size the same, but that could get messy.